# Deleting from SQLite table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

I am running the following command to delete a tuple from the table in SQLite but i get an error

```
DELETE FROM Students S where S.name="Smith"
```

I am sure that there is an entry named Smith, and i am sure there is a column named "name". Here is the error message:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: delete from Students S where S.name="Smith"
[ near "S": syntax error ] Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE Exception Message: 
Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)                     
[mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

I think it is about renaming the table:"Students S", but i cannot find a solution.
Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL you delimit strings with single, not double quotes. In addition, you do not alias tables in `DELETE` statements in the way that you did:

```
DELETE FROM Students where name='Smith'
```

If you must use an alias, this syntax should work:

```
DELETE s from Students s WHERE s.name='Smith'
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but i tried with double quotes, it also worked. The code i tried was written in the book i am reading (Database management systems by Ramakrishnan). Why didn't it work? Is the book wrong or renaming the table like Students S, and S.name is a general way of showing the commands?

Comment: @bigO I suspect that there are dialects of SQL that take the syntax from the book. However, I can't name one off the top of my head that would allow a "plain" aliased syntax from your example.

Comment: @CobraAjgar whenever i say an answer works, everbody says "accept the answer", please keep in mind that system says "you can accept answer in ... minutes". I know i have to accept the answer if it works.

dasblinkenlight thanks again